# "Incorrect padding" when base64 decoding Gmail message in Python

Tags: python, base64, gmail

I'm working with the Gmail API, getting a weird error when base64 decoding some parts a message: `binascii.Error: Incorrect padding`. I'm requesting the `full` format. Google's response confirms that encoding is base64:

```
{"name": "Content-Transfer-Encoding", "value": "base64"}
```

My code:

```
message = self.service.users().messages().get(
    userId=user_id,
    id=message_id,
    format=message_format,
).execute()

base64.b64decode(message["payload"]["parts"][0]["body"]["data"])
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/base64.py", line 88, in b64decode
    return binascii.a2b_base64(s, strict_mode=validate)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
binascii.Error: Incorrect padding
```

Oddly, I don't get this error if I decode a different part of the message, eg `message['payload']['parts'][1]['body']['data']`.

Answer (score 0):

Update - turns out Gmail actually sends emails as `base64url` encoded. From their docs:

```
Emails are sent as base64url encoded strings within the raw property of a message resource.
```

Switching the code above to use `base64.urlsafe_b64decode` resolved the error.